# Codeigniter 2.1 - active record

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I have reached dead end with the brain o.O. In DB I have two tables:

**store_module->caffe_id, module_id, position, order**

**module->id_module, name, description, image**

I have query where I take all modules for set ID (store_module table), and I need to get all modules which appear in this query (module_id). What I need to do? 
This is the code (I am awake for 30+ hours and my brain is refusing to communicate with me, deadline is almost here, and this on of the last things I need to do. So, please help :D):

```
function mar_get_modules($id){
            $q = $this->db->get_where('store_module', array('caffe_id' => $id));
            $modules = $q->result_array();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start simple, by using a regular query (if I guess right, you need a JOIN there).
This query should work:

```
$sql = "SELECT m.*,sm.* FROM module m
       LEFT JOIN store_module sm ON sm.id_module = m.module_id
       WHERE sm.caffe_id = ?";
return $this->db->query($sql, array($id))->result_array();
```

Now, you can transform it into an AR query:

```
$query = $this->db->select('module.*,store_module.*')
                  ->from('module')
                  ->join('store_module', 'store_module.id_module = module.module_id','left')
                  ->where('store_module.caffe_id',$id)
                  ->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

While AR is quicker sometimes, I usually prefer writing my queries "by hand", taking advantage of the binding to prevent SQL injections; it's a lot easier to see how things are working if you have a query fully laid under your eyes

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you a lot :), you have no idea how much you helped me :D. Sleep here I come :).

Answer (score 0):

Sasha,

In the function above, you are not returning anything.  You'll need to update the 3rd line something to the effect of `return $q->result_array();`

Comment: At the moment I am not trying to return anything, I need to run some kind of query to get data from **module** table.

Comment: @Sasha, I may not be understanding what you are trying to accomplish.  But I'm wondering, how are you going to determine if it's working if you don't do any return or output?  It could be pulling the data you desire, but if you don't do anything with it, you would never know.  Let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: I have hard time to explain this to myself :D. In the table **store_module** there is the field **module_id**, and there are multiple results. From the table **module** I need to get data where **module_id = id_module** (for the every field found in the original query)